# Emulator on Android Studio doesn't run

Tags: android

I'm new to android studio, so I don't know why the emulator isn't working. I don't get any errors, it even says it has a successful build but the emulator just sits there and at the bottom it says waiting for all target devices to come online. I've tried invaliding the cashes, I've deleted and re-created a new device, I've wiped the AVD data. No matter what I do it won't load the emulator. Does anyone have a clue what going on because I really need some help please.

I've tried invaliding the cashes, I've deleted and re-created a new device, I've wiped the AVD data. No matter what I do it won't load the emulator. Does anyone have a clue what going on because I really need some help please.

Comment: Hi, Steven! Could you provide more details on your setup? Which OS do you use? Which processor do you have? Have you enabled [hardware acceleration](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration)?

Comment: Thank you Ivan, I'm using a 64-bit on Windows 10, I have a Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4930K CPU @ 3.40GHz   3.40 GHz, and yes I tried setting up an AVD using hardware but when I click built it starts running the emulator then quits. There's no error, its like magikarp using splash (but nothing happened)

Comment: Okay, here is some advice: double-check that you have installed tools for the emulator in Android SDK settings; check that hardware acceleration is enabled in the boot menu; try running the emulator from the console to see errors there; try creating another emulator with a different Android version.

Comment: So I've made a Pixel 6 pro using Tiramisu, and on the Verify Configurations>Emulated Preferences I've set the graphics to Hardware - GLES 2.0. I'm using this model because I have this phone, my though was that I could use the emulator to set up the basics of the app and then when I have something that is functional I could test it on the phone.

Comment: The device model doesn't affect the startup of the emulator mostly. It's an emulator image that can be broken. So if you try different emulator images that may help, because some of them may not work properly in the specific environment.